# "Anti-curl" operator in a topologically non-trivial domain

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

$\DeclareMathOperator{\div}{div}\DeclareMathOperator{\rot}{rot}$Let $D$ be an open bounded connected domain in $\mathbb R^3$ and let $X$ be a smooth vector field in $D$ such that
$$
   \int_S X \cdot dS = 0 \tag{1}
$$
for any closed surface $S$ in $D$. In particular, $\mathop{\mathrm{div}} X = 0$ in $D$ since
$$
   \mathop{\mathrm{div}} X(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to +0} \tfrac{3}{4\pi \varepsilon^3} \int_{|x-y| = \varepsilon} X(y) \cdot dS_y = 0
$$
by the Ostrogradski-Gauss formula and the mean-value formula. But condition (1) is stronger than just $\mathop{\mathrm{div}} X = 0$ in $D$, it also means that $X \cdot dS$ integrates to $0$ for any closed surface $S$ enclosing a "hole" in $D$.

I think that (1) implies that $X = \mathop{\mathrm{rot}} B$ for some smooth vector field $B$ in $D$, and I think that I can show it using differential forms. But is it possible to prove this and to find an explicit expression for such $B$ using "elementary" tools (without de Rham's theorem)?

Here are some thoughts. As $\div X = 0$, there exists a small covering of $D$ by $U_\alpha$'s such that $X = \rot Y_\alpha$ in $U_\alpha$. Then
$$
   Y_\alpha - Y_\beta = \nabla \varphi_{\alpha\beta} \quad \text{in $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$},
$$
for some $\varphi_{\alpha\beta} \in C^\infty(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta)$ such that $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}+\varphi_{\beta\alpha}=0$. Next,
$$
   \varphi_{\alpha \beta}+\varphi_{\beta\gamma}+\varphi_{\gamma\alpha} = c_{\alpha\beta\gamma} \in \mathbb R \quad \text{in $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \cap U_\gamma$}
$$
where $c_{\alpha\beta\gamma}$ satisfy the $2$-cocycle conditions. Condition (1) must somehow imply that $c_{\alpha\beta\gamma}$ is a $2$-coboundary but I don't see why. I tried to rewrite (1) as
$$
  \int_S X \cdot dS = \sum_\alpha \int_{S\cap U_\alpha} \rot Y_\alpha \cdot dS - \sum_{\alpha\beta}\int_{S \cap U_\alpha \cap U_\beta} \rot Y_\alpha\cdot dS + \sum_{\alpha\beta\gamma}\int_{S \cap U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \cap U_\gamma} \rot Y_\alpha \cdot dS \\
 = \sum_\alpha \int_{S \cap \partial U_\alpha} Y_\alpha \cdot dl+ \cdots = 0
$$
but I don't see how to deduce from here some equations on $c_{\alpha\beta\gamma}$.

Comment: I think that (1) is _equivalent_ to the existence of $B$ with $X = \text{curl}(B)$. Of course, $B$ will not be unique (the vector field $B + \text{grad}(f)$ for any function $f$ also works). Solving for $B$ amounts to solving a system of three first-order PDE for the components of $B$. In the absence of additional conditions on $X$, I think it's unlikely that an explicit formula for (all such) $B$ exists.

Comment: But maybe it depends what one means by "explicit."  Do integral representation formulas count?  See the [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Statement_of_the_theorem)

Comment: @JesseMadnick The Helmholtz decomposition was the first thing I tried to adapt to this context. But here the function may behave very bad as a point approaches the boundary. By the way, in the case of an open unit ball with a point removed (I think it is the simplest possible case) is it possible to give an explicit formula? (Avoid solving a system of PDEs)

Comment: This is a nice, natural question. I asked the more general version of this question both here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186258/proving-the-injectivity-half-of-de-rhams-theorem-when-p1-if-a-p-form-om) and on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199886/proving-the-injectivity-half-of-de-rhams-theorem-by-construction-in-degrees-oth.